# Decode image file to extract image header information and modify it (with python)

Tags: python

I'm reading an image file of dpx format, and want to extract the "Orientation" in the image section of the header, and also modify it. I have never tried to interpret binary data, so I'm a bit at a loss. I'm trying to use the struct module, but I really don't know how to do it properly. The file header specification is here:

http://www.fileformat.info/format/dpx/egff.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a constant offset to the Orientation so if this is all you want to change then I wouldn't bother trying to parse it all, just work out the offset (which I think is just the size of the `GENERICFILEHEADER` plus one byte for the high byte of the orientation word) and read / manipulate it directly.

Using a bytearray would be my first choice. The offset varies by one depending on if it's in a big or little endian format, so something like this might work for you:

```
b = bytearray(your_byte_data)
big_endian = (b[0] == 0x52)
offset = 768 + big_endian
current_orientation = b[offset]  # get current orientation
b[offset] = new_offset           # set it to something new
open('out_file', 'wb').write(b)
```

Comment: Hi, when writing the offset value, can I just assign it an integer directly? Or do I need to convert in some way? Anyway, your solutions seems to work for the most part.

Comment: Yes, it works but for some reason it's not doing what I expected. I get a value of 0, and according to the specification it can get a value from 0 to 7, however any other value than 0 does not get recognized, but I guess this has to do with the file itself, and your solution is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [Imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do that. Open source and supports the dpx format.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Imaging Library PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) has am attribute .info that might return the relevant data