# Working out bytearray offset in an image(dpx) file

Tags: python, image, file, header, arrays

I Have been working on reading binary data every now and then. But i have never really gotten the system down on how to extrapolate the offsets when using a bytearray.

in this case i am working on a dpx file and trying to change the aspectratio located in the Orientation Header. 
relevant file info found here: http://www.fileformat.info/format/dpx/egff.htm

I know Scott Griffiths has a great post on the subject.[Decode image file to extract image header information and modify it (with python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249748/decode-image-file-to-extract-image-header-information-and-modify-it-with-python)
 However i never really understood enough to convert that knowledge into modifying things under other headers than the GENERICFILEHEADER

So how would one go about changing the aspectratio. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice document called "File Format for Digital Moving-Picture Exchange" that I think might help you out.  I'm not sure where the official version lives, but one version is [here](http://www.simplesystems.org/users/bfriesen/dpx/S268M_Revised.pdf).

Anyway, here's a code snippet that you could use to change the pixel aspect ratio:

```
import struct

fp = open('file.dpx', 'r+b')
fp.seek(1628) #Set the offset to the pixel aspect ratio field

#Prints out the current pixel aspect ratio. 
#Assumes big-endian -- Check the magic number for your use case
print struct.unpack_from('>I', fp.read(4))[0] #horizontal pixel aspect ratio
print struct.unpack_from('>I', fp.read(4))[0] #vertical pixel aspect ratio

#Change the aspect ratios to new values.  Again assumes big-endian
fp.seek(1628) #Return to the proper offset for aspect ratio
new_horizontal = struct.pack('>I', 4L) 
new_vertical = struct.pack('>I', 3L) 
fp.write(new_horizontal) #set the new horizontal pixel aspect ratio to 4
fp.write(new_vertical) #set the new vertical aspect ratio to 3
fp.close()
```

This code assumes that you haven't read the File Header and Image Header yet.  The File Header is 768 bytes, and the Image Header is 640 bytes.  Then there are several fields in the Orientation Header before AspectRatio: XOffset, YOffset, XCenter, YCenter, XOriginalSize, YOriginalSize, FileName, TimeDate, InputName, InputSN, and Border.  These fields have byte lengths of 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 100, 24, 32, 32, and 8 respectively; for a total of 220.  The offset for the AspectRatio is the sum of these fields: 768+640+220=1628.

That's the hard way to figure out the proper offset.  It's much easier if you just look at the .pdf listed above.  It lists all of the field offsets in the tables :p

Comment: Hey, thanks for a speedy reply. The code snippet is much appreciated.How did you work on the offset for the aspectratio. It says the orientationheader is 256 bytes long. I just didnt get that to fit with the offset of 1628.

Comment: Great stuff. this insight into binary offsets has been great. Thanks for lending your time. Changed the code abit since python 2.6 doesnt seem to like the write command in 'rb' mode changed it to 'rb+' and it seems to work fine